# Error: Unknown constructor 'CustomInv.CustomInv()'

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom controller CustomInv. The Code for this is as below:

```
public with sharing class CustomInv {
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}

    public  List<npe01__OppPayment__c>  Rec {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> Contact {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> Contact1 {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> Contact2 {get; set;}

    ApexPages.StandardController standrdCntrl;

    public CustomInv(ApexPages.StandardController cntrl){
        standrdCntrl=cntrl;
        this.opp = (Opportunity) standrdCntrl.getRecord();
        Contact = [SELECT Name, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE  AccountId=: opp.AccountId and (Title='Primary_M' or Title='Primary_D')  limit 1] ;
        Contact1 = [SELECT Name, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE  AccountId=: opp.AccountId and (Title='Primary_M')  limit 1] ;
        Contact2 = [SELECT Name, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE  AccountId=: opp.AccountId and (Title='Primary_D')  limit 1] ;
        Rec =[Select CreatedDate, SystemModstamp,npe01__Payment_Amount__c, npe01__Opportunity__c, npe01__Paid__c, npe01__Scheduled_Date__c FROM npe01__OppPayment__c WHERE npe01__Paid__c = true and  npe01__Opportunity__c = : ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') limit 200];
    }
}
```

I am using this controller in a Visualforce Component CustComp.vfc with the code:

```
<apex:component controller="CustomInv" access="global">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
<tr>
<td>
    <img src='{!URLFOR($Resource.Logo4567687)}' title="logo" />

</td>
<p align="center"><font face="Arial"><i>{!$Organization.Name}</i></font>  <br/>
<font face="Arial"><i>{!$Organization.Street}</i></font><br/>
<font face="Arial"><i>{!$Organization.City}</i></font>
<font face="Arial"><i>,{!$Organization.State}</i></font>
<font face="Arial"><i>{!$Organization.PostalCode}</i></font></p>
<!--<td  align="right"><font face="Arial" >
<b>Invoice for {!Opportunity.Account.Name}</b></font><br/>
</td>-->
</tr>

<hr/>

</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
<tr>    <td width="65%"><font face="Arial" >
    Federal Tax ID: 27-0580207<br/>
    </font></td> 
    <!--<td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>-->
<td width="50%"><font face="Arial">Invoice number: <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.Invoices__r}" var="line2">
{!line2.name}</apex:repeat></font><br/> 
<font face="Arial">Invoice Date: <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.Invoices__r}" var="line2">
{!line2.Invoice_Date__c} </apex:repeat></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<hr/>
<p><b><font face="Arial" color="#000080">Account Information</font></b></p>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table2">
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
       <font face="Arial">Child name: {!Opportunity.Account.Name} <br/><br/>    </font>
   </td>
</tr>
Parent Name:
<!--<apex:dataList value="{!Contact}" var="con">

<tr>
   <td>          
       <font face="Arial"> {!con.Name}<br/>
                         {!Opportunity.Account.BillingStreet}<br/>
                         {!Opportunity.Account.BillingPostalCode} {!Opportunity.Account.BillingCity}
       </font>
    </td>

</tr> 
</apex:dataList> -->
<!-- <apex:repeat value="{!Contact}" var="con">-->

<apex:repeat value="{!Contact1}" var="con1">

<apex:repeat value="{!Contact2}" var="con2">
<tr>
   <td colspan="3">          
       <font face="Arial"> {!IF(((Opportunity.Description=='Mother')||(Opportunity.Description=='mother')||(Opportunity.Description=='Mom')||(Opportunity.Description=='mom')),con1.Name,IF((Opportunity.Description=='Father')||(Opportunity.Description=='father')||(Opportunity.Description=='Dad')||(Opportunity.Description=='dad'),con2.Name, 'con.Name'))}<br/>

                         {!Opportunity.Account.BillingStreet}<br/>
                         {!Opportunity.Account.BillingPostalCode} {!Opportunity.Account.BillingCity}
       </font>
    </td>    
</tr> 

</apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>

</table>
<br/>
<hr/>
<p><b><font color="#000080" face="Arial">Invoice Detail</font></b></p>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table4">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Item</font></td>
<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Description</font></td>
<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">List Price</font></td>
<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Qty</font></td>
<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Total Price</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="line">

      <tr>
          <td>{!line.PricebookEntry.Name}</td>
          <td>{!line.Description}</td>
          <td>{!line.ListPrice}</td>
          <td>{!line.Quantity}</td>
          <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.SubTotal_Price__c}"/></td>
      </tr>
   </apex:repeat>
</tr>

<tr>

   <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="right" colspan="4">
   <font face="Arial"><b>Total:</b>&nbsp;<apex:OutputField value="{!Opportunity.Total_Amount__c}"/></font></td>
</tr>

</table>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table4">
<tr>
   <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Post Date</font></td> 
   <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Due Date</font></td>        
   <!--<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Description</font></td>  -->  
   <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Credit</font></td>
   <!--<td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Debit</font></td>  -->    
</tr>
<apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>
 <apex:repeat value="{!Rec}" var="Pay">
     <tr>

         <td> {!Pay.npe01__Scheduled_Date__c}
         <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"  /></td>
         <td>{!Pay.npe01__Scheduled_Date__c}</td>             
         <!--<td>{!line.Description}</td> -->                       
         <td><apex:OutputField value="{!Pay.npe01__Payment_Amount__c}"/>    </td>
         <!--<apex:variable value="{!Opportunity.Amount}" var="amt"/>
         <apex:variable value="{!Pay.npe01__Payment_Amount__c}" var="pmt"/>
         <td><apex:variable value="{!(amt-pmt)}" var="debit1"/>
         <apex:variable value="{!((-pmt*(rowNum-2))-pmt)}" var="debit2"/>

         $<apex:outputText value="{!debit1}"/></td>-->

      </tr>
    </apex:repeat>

  <tr>

   <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="right" colspan="2">
   <font face="Arial"><b>Total Credit:</b>&nbsp;<apex:OutputField value="{!Opportunity.npe01__Payments_Made__c}"/></font></td>
   <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="right" colspan="4">
   <font face="Arial"><b>Balance:</b>&nbsp;<apex:OutputField value="{!Opportunity.Balance_Remaining__c}"/></font></td>
</tr> 



</table>
<br/>
<hr/>

<p align="center"><font face="Arial"><i>Copyright {!$Organization.Name}.</i>    </font></p>
</apex:component>
```

I need to use this VF Component in a Visualforce  Email Template..

But I get the error Unknown constructor 'CustomInv.CustomInv()' in CustComp.vfc 
If I give a constructor with no parameters, it gives the error Unknown property 'CustomInv.Opportunity.

I am unable to identify why it gives this error. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assumes you are using a `StandardController`. In other words, it is an *extension*. Either change your page declaration to:

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c" extensions="CustomInv">
```

or add an empty constructor (making it a *controller*):

```
public with sharing class CustomInv
{
    public CustomInv()
    {
        // constructor logic.
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use a visualforce component instead of a page as I mentioned earlier this component needs to be added to a visualforce email template. Second adding a empty constructor gives the error Unknown property 'CustomInv.Opportunity

Comment: That means you need the latter option. You need to change `Opportunity` to `opp`.  You need to pass it in using `apex:attribute` tags.